# How to fix "No observables detected in the build method of Observer" in Flutter MobX?

Tags: flutter, dart, observable, mobx

I'm encountering the "No observables detected in the build method of Observer" error in my Flutter MobX project. Here's the relevant code and error message.

**Error Message:**

```
I/flutter (15344): No observables detected in the build method of Observer 
I/flutter (15344): Observer constructed from: Cronometro.build (package:braintrinig/components/cronometro.dart:29:11) 
...
```

**Code:**

```
class Cronometro extends StatelessWidget {
  const Cronometro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final store = Provider.of<PomodoroStore>(context);

    return Container(
      color: store.isWorking() ?  Colors.redAccent : Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
          store.isWorking() ? "Time to work" : "Time to rest",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 40,
          color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Observer(
            builder: (_) => Text(
            '${store.minutos.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${store.segundos.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 120,
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Observer(builder: (_) => SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                if(!store.start)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: CronometroButton(
                      text: 'Start',
                      icon: Icons.play_arrow,
                      click: store.startworking,
                    ),
                  ),
                if(store.start)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: CronometroButton(
                      text: 'Stop',
                      icon: Icons.stop,
                      click: store.stop,
                    ),
                  ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: CronometroButton(
                    text: 'Restart',
                    icon: Icons.refresh,
                    click: store.restart,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Context:** The error occurs within my `Cronometro` widget. I believe the issue is related to how I'm using MobX observables, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Observer`s when using `provider`. [Observer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobx) is used with `MobX`.